# Insert JS in PHP - on load scroll

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, templates

I'm trying to get my page to scroll to a certain number of pixels down the page when it loads. I'm editing a wordpress template that I created so it's in PHP.

I've got:

```
<?php
echo "<body onload='window.scroll(0,400)'>";
?>
```

at the top of the php file but it's not working. what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: I believe you might want to use `scrollTo` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Comment: @ramraider: don't link to/cite w3fools. they're a crap resource

Comment: seems a tad harse and possibly biased @Marc B - perhaps then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo might be more appropriate

Comment: @RamRaider: they should spend more time producing good quality examples, rather than on SEO operations. being high up in google results doesn't mean theyr'e any good. a lot of their code samples are bad and/or outright dangerous.

Comment: to be honest I've never paid much attention to them, have no knowledge of their practises or really wasted time and effort thinking about them - it just happened to be the first result that popped up in the all powerful google and was, I thought, applicable to the OP's question/problem. I shall endeavour to be more Mozilla orientated when sharing links in the future

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your `header.php` on your child theme or any similar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        window.scroll(0,400);
    });
</script>
```

Don't forget insert jquery in your head if this code not working

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you Quynh! I need this to work only on a specific page, so unless I made a custom header for this page, this wouldn't work for what I need. Khris gave me the inline code which works great.

Comment: @user2765920 You just use is_page($id) and echo that source. Anyway you solved your issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The onload event attribute is expecting a function, and you can do that inline with `javascript:` in the attribute...

```
<?php
echo "<body onload='javascript:window.scroll(0,400);'>";
?>
```

Comment: This worked perfect. Thank you Khris! I would give you one up but I don't have any reputation here.

Comment: I believe you can still mark this as the correct answer by clicking the checkbox next to the question.